# Bookmarklet to click a specific div element with no id

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I need a bookmarklet to click one of many div elements with the class `"site-label-text selectedResource"`. I know how to write a bookmarklet that clicks on an element by the element's `ID` or `name`, but this particular element has neither.

The specific element I want to click can be identified by its `innerText` or `textContent` properties, which are both `"33"`.

I was going to try searching the text contents of all elements with the class `"site-label-text selectedResource"`, but it seems that, in bookmarklets, `getElementBy__` works, but `getElementsBy__` (plural) doesn't. And even if that worked, I'm not sure how I can use that to specify the element I want clicked.

Another option I've read about is to use the XPATH. I found the element's XPATH

```
/html/body/app-root/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div[2]/main/app-create-booking/app-search-results/div/div[2]/div/app-map-view/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[167]
```

but I don't know the command to "click" it.

So I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a sample snippet of the HTML that surrounds the element you want? a `document.querySelectorAll(...);` query might help you get what you need?

Comment: BTW there might be some other keys for targeting your element: attributes, sibling elements or even text content or combinations of all of these, so targetig 167th child might be unnecessary.

Comment: @scunliffe Here's what else is around it. Notably, the same information pops up when clicking on the element immediately above this one (one's text and the other is an icon - both for the same item).

![Screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/M3t0a9.jpg)

Comment: @myf Here are the DOM Properties of the element:

[Screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/RBKN2O.jpg)

Comment: @myf Actually, those are the properties of the text in the element. The properties of the element I was initially referring to are: [Screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/YdAU9x.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select multiple elements based on a class-name you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

It should look something like this:

```
javascript: (() => {
  // Select all elements with target class-name.
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.site-label-text selectedResource');

  // Filter those elements based on their contents.
  const filteredElements = [...elements].filter(e => e.innerHTML === '33');

  // Synthesize a "click" event.
  filteredElements.forEach(e => e.click());
})();
```

Comment: There's an error: `TypeError: elements.filter is not a function`

[Screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/gGU2ky.jpg)

Comment: True, need to first copy the array to allow filtering it in this case, this is due to it being of type `NodeList`. Updating the snippet.